# TYPO3 DCE with fatal error in typo3temp output_tca_and_flexform.php

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, dce

**Version**

- TYPO3: 8.5.34
- PHP: 7.4
- DCE: 2.6.1

I get the following error message intermittently.

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/public/typo3temp/var/Cache/cache_dce/output_tca_and_flexform.php'

My website is then broken and can only be restored by deleting the TYPO3 cache.

Comment: When it occurs, does `/public/typo3temp/var/Cache/cache_dce/output_tca_and_flexform.php` exist? Has it content? Is it readable for the webserver-user?

Comment: The file does not exist.

Comment: Maybe a quota problem, so TYPO3 wasn't able to write it?